# ASP.Net - VB - Gridview & number sorting with 5 and 6 digits

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, datagrid

I'm trying to find an elegant way to solve this:

[image]

I have got a gridview and when I sort for "Site ID", since I have values with 5 and 6 digits, it gets fooled on the number progression.

I perfectly know that it could be solved simply adding a 0 in between the 5 digits code (i.e. BV0100 instead of BV100), but for several reasons this approach is going to result in unwanted after effects for the end users.

Is there a more elegant way to solve it?
I was thinking that maybe it's somehow possible to act on the binary comparison that gets you to the datagrid sorting, but honestly I don't even know where to start for something similar. I'm not even sure it's possible nor it's the correct approach.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Regards.

Comment: The general strategy for this kind of sort is to special-case when you hit a numeric sequence in the string.  I'm not sure of the datagrid capabilities, but if it lets you provide a custom sort, this isn't that difficult to do.

Comment: Hi Craig, thanks for the reply. Well as far as I know the properties to play with for the sorting are sortexpression (the column to sort) and sortdirection (ASC, DESC). I'm not aware of any more refined properties or methods to reach the result I want. By the way, can you please make an example of what you mean "to special-case", it's the first time I face this term. Thank you.

Comment: The easiest way to do custom sorting is to customize the comparison between two items.  In the general case for a string, you step through characters in both strings under comparison until you find differing characters (or a difference in length), and that sets the result of the comparison.  The special case is that when you hit digits in both strings, you then switch over to parsing as numbers (so that a string with a sequence "100" will sort as greater than one with a sequence "99").  It's a special case in the processing, so I verbified it as "to special-case".

Comment: Ok thanks Craig, I get the general idea now, I will try to deep dive this method.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Craig suggestion I have deep dived his method, but in the end found what I think to be the easiest solution for my problem.

I have added to that db table a column named "Full ID" where the IDs are all made of 6 digits.

Then on the aspx page I have added to the gridview this hidden column:

```html
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Full ID" HeaderText="Full ID" SortExpression="Full ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol">
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="hiddencol"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle CssClass="hiddencol"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
```

Then I have changed in the gridview the sortexpression parameter of the "Site ID" column to "Full ID".

```html
<asp:BoundField DataField="Site ID" HeaderText="Site ID" SortExpression="Full ID" />
```

The control that's sorting in the end is the datasource, while the gridview only takes care of the UI and to pass the sortexpression to the datasource.

Hope this might help someone else in the future.

@Craig your solution was way more elegant than mine, but in the end for me it's ok this way as long as the end user doesn't see the lack of elegance. :)

Comment: Your solution is a fine approach given the data you have at your disposal.  My suggestion is more appropriate when all you have to work with are strings (and even then it has some limitations).